# VBA Word How do I pass part of an array to a subroutine?

Tags: arrays, vba, ms-word, subroutine

I want to pass a part of an array to a subroutine!

```
Sub main()
    Dim i(10) As Byte
    Dim j As Integer

    For j = LBound(i) To UBound(i)
        i(j) = j
    Next
    
    Call subr(i())

End Sub
Sub subr(i() As Byte)
    Dim j As Integer

    For j = LBound(i) To UBound(i)
        Debug.Print  i(j)
    Next
    
End Sub
```

This example passes the entire array to *subr* and prints it.

I want something like this (which doesn't work):

```
Call subr(i(L_index to U_index))
```

*L_index* and *U_index* determine the range to pass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do that would be to copy the span of the array your interested
in, instead pass the array & range:

```
Call subr(i(), 3, 5)
```

---

```
Sub subr(arr() As Byte, startIndex As Long, endIndex As Long)
   
   For i = startIndex To endIndex
        Debug.Print arr(i)
   Next
    
End Sub
```